# How to get a cropped image from another by comparing to low resolution cropped image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two images one image is in high resolution and other is a part of the that image but in low resolution.

Is there a way so that i can compare the low resolution part to the high resolution image and get the same(which is part of the image) in high resolution?

I have found library OPENCV which can be used for image comparison but not sure how effective it will be in this case.
Also are there any other libraries that can be used for the same?

Comment: asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic. please read [ask]. you can solve this problem using opencv and pretty much any other image processing library out there. what works best for you is up to you. language preferences, operating system,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use many methods to find the low-resolution template in a high-resolution image containing it. The easiest way is basic template matching. From code taken directly from an [OpenCV template matching tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html), I was able to find this low-res template:

[image: Low-res image]

in the following image:

[image: High-res image with low-res template found]

Images from [Oxford's VGG](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data5.html).